# Cache last emitted item RxJava Operator

Tags: rx-java

Is there an operator that caches the last emitted item and passes it to every new subscriber? In other words, an operator that makes an observable to behave like a `BehaviorSubject`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. but in a 3rd party library called ReplayingShare. Here is the link:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare

Compare to `.replay(1).autoConnect()` It can disconnect from upstream if there are no subscriber at downstream.

Compare to `.replay(1).refCount()`It can also cache the last value even you've already disconnected from it.

Also, if upstream ended (no matter which you use `refCount`/`autoConnect`), you won't get your replay for next subscriber. But with ReplayingShare you will always get your last item cache.

Comment: From ReplayingShare github page: "Any terminal event will clear the cached value." Doesn't that mean value would be cleared if upstream ended ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use `replay(bufferSize)` operator with param of 1, from the [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#replay(int)):

> Returns a ConnectableObservable that shares a single subscription to the source Observable that replays at most bufferSize items emitted by that Observable

replay will cache last item, and replay it to any new subscriber, please note that it's `ConnectableObservable` so you must invoke `connect()` to make it start emit items, or use `refCount()` to get an `Observable` that does it automatically with first `Subscriber`, and unsubscribe when the last subscription unsubscribed.